# How to properly use log_daemon_msg, log_end_msg, log_progress_msg to write a proper daemon script?

Tags: daemon

I was suprised not to be able to find any documentation regarding the proper user of these functions:

```
log_daemon_msg
log_progress_msg
log_end_msg
log_action_msg
log_success_msg
log_failure_msg
log_warning_msg
```

Where can I find more information about their usage and maybe other related functions?

Note, I found them inside `/lib/lsb/init-functions` but the is documentation regarding their usage is mostly missing.

Comment: Good question. I've been trying to find documentation on the subject too

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptfunc.html

I've been reading a lot of init scripts on debian wheezy but there doesn't seems to be a unified way of creating init scripts. Some people use `echo` instead of `log_warning_msg` or `log_failure_msg`.

Note: `/lib/lsb/init-functions` doesn't seem to work well under bash. So remember to use the appropriate shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Comment: The LSB spec does not include log_progress_msg

Comment: Nor `log_end_msg`

Comment: Where those logs are saved?

Comment: @Josir the messages are sent to stdout and/or error. You'll have to take care of it.

Comment: As the script is controlled by init.d, I don't know how to "take care of it". Anyway, I created a specific question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69757333/how-can-i-define-where-log-daemon-msg-log-end-msg-log-progress-msg-will-be-sto

Answer (score 2):

just try to test that with any script:

vim 123.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

[ 1 != 2 ] && log_end_msg 1
```

So I`ve included funcs from /lib/lsb/init-functions.

And execute:

```
bash 123.sh 
   ...fail!
```

And so on:

```
cat 123.sh 
#!/bin/sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

[ 1 != 2 ] && log_end_msg 0
```

And run:

```
bash 123.sh 
   ...done.
```